# Why does my SMTP Client produce no output when typing in the terminal?

Tags: java, email, intellij-idea, smtp

I've been using IntelliJ to test out my SMTP Java client-server protocol. I've been testing some code on my Client java file to allow me input text.

The output i want to achieve in the end should look a little something like this:

```
s: 220 [my ip]
c: HELLO [my email]
s: 250 Hello [my email], pleased to meet you
c: MAIL FROM <[my email]>
s: 250 ok
c: RCPT TO: <[test email]>
s: 250 ok
c: DATA
s: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
c: Hello loan team,
c: If i don't stay, will i lose my loan?
c: .
s: 250 ok Message accepted for delivery
c: QUIT
s: 221 [my ip] closing connection
```

When i run my server code first, then my client code afterwards, it connects to the server but there's no output in the terminal. Even when i type something in the terminal, nothing outputs and i'm stumped if the Client code is causing problems, or the Server code is causing problems? Just to let you know that both code compiles and runs without errors.

Edit 1: I went back to the tutorial i followed and typed in the same socket ip and port and the Client code worked perfectly fine, following the tutorial. So i've denounced that the Server code is the problem. The main question is how do i alter the TCPServer code to fit the requirements of a simple SMTP server?

TCPServer.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPServer{
    private ServerSocket server;

    /**
     * The TCPServer constructor initiate the socket
     * @param ipAddress
     * @param port
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public TCPServer(String ipAddress, int port) throws Exception {
        if (ipAddress != null && !ipAddress.isEmpty())
            this.server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));
        else
            this.server = new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }

    /**
     * The listen method listen to incoming client's datagrams and requests
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void listen() throws Exception {
        // listen to incoming client's requests via the ServerSocket
        //add your code here
        String data = null;
        Socket client = this.server.accept();
        String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("\r\nNew client connection from " + clientAddress);

        // print received datagrams from client
        //add your code here
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            System.out.println("\r\nMessage from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);
            client.sendUrgentData(1);
        }
    }

    public InetAddress getSocketAddress() {
        return this.server.getInetAddress();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.server.getLocalPort();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set the server address (IP) and port number
        //add your code here
        String serverIP = "192.168.1.235"; // local IP address
        int port = 8088;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverIP = args[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }
        // call the constructor and pass the IP and port
        //add your code here
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer(serverIP, port);
        System.out.println("\r\nRunning Server: " +
                "Host=" + server.getSocketAddress().getHostAddress() +
                " Port=" + server.getPort());
        server.listen();
    }

}
```

And here's ClientTester.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientTester{
    private Socket tcpSocket;
    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int serverPort;
    private Scanner scanner;

    /**
     * @param serverAddress
     * @param serverPort
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private ClientTester(InetAddress serverAddress, int serverPort) throws Exception {
        this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;

        //Initiate the connection with the server using Socket.
        //For this, creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number at the specified IP address.
        //add your code here
        this.tcpSocket = new Socket(this.serverAddress, this.serverPort);
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * The start method connect to the server and datagrams
     * @throws IOException
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set the server address (IP) and port number
        //add your code here
        InetAddress serverIP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.235"); // local IP address
        int port = 8088;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverIP = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }

        // call the constructor and pass the IP and port
        //add your code here
        ClientTester client = new ClientTester(serverIP, port);

//        client.start();

        try{

            client = new ClientTester(serverIP, port);

            System.out.println("\r\n Connected to Server: " + client.tcpSocket.getInetAddress());

            BufferedReader stdin;
            stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

            InputStream is = client.tcpSocket.getInputStream ();
            BufferedReader sockin;
            sockin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));

            OutputStream os = client.tcpSocket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter sockout;
            sockout = new PrintWriter (os, true);

            System.out.println ("S:" + sockin.readLine ());

            while (true){
                System.out.print ("C:");

                String cmd = stdin.readLine ();

                sockout.println (cmd);

                String reply = sockin.readLine ();

                System.out.println ("S:" + reply);
                if (cmd.toLowerCase ().startsWith ("data") &&
                        reply.substring (0, 3).equals ("354"))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        cmd = stdin.readLine ();

                        if (cmd != null && cmd.length () > 1 &&
                                cmd.charAt (0) == '.')
                            cmd = "."; // Must be no chars after . char.

                        sockout.println (cmd);

                        if (cmd.equals ("."))
                            break;
                    }
                    while (true);

                    // Read a reply string from the SMTP server program.

                    reply = sockin.readLine ();

                    // Display the first line of this reply string.

                    System.out.println ("S:" + reply);

                    continue;
                }

                // If the QUIT command was entered, quit.

                if (cmd.toLowerCase ().startsWith ("quit"))
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println (e.toString ());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                // Attempt to close the client socket.

                if (client != null)
                    client.tcpSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Hopefully what i've written made somewhat sense of what problems i am encountering.

Comment: Edit 1: I went back to the tutorial i followed and typed in the same socket ip and port and the Client code worked perfectly fine, following the tutorial. So i've denounced that the Server code is the problem. The main question is how do i alter the TCPServer code to fit the requirements of a simple SMTP server?

Comment: Which tutorial?